# Pointer Addressing in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I am trying to understand why memory addresses for pointers increment a certain number of bytes based on datatype.

The following code creates an array of four small integers then iterates through the memory addresses holding them, byte by byte.  It appears the integers are stored in the 0 byte and random values in bytes 1-3:

```
        int ia[] = {1, 3, 4, 7};

    printf("Address of Int Array 0 is: %p\n", &ia[0]);
    printf("Address of Int Array 1 is: %p\n", &ia[1]);
    printf("Address of Int Array 2 is: %p\n", &ia[2]);
    printf("Address of Int Array 3 is: %p\n", &ia[3]);

    void *addr = (void *) &ia[0];

    printf("\nAddress: %p\n", addr);
    printf("Data:  %d\n", *((int*) addr));

    addr = addr+1;

    printf("\nAddress: %p\n", addr);
    printf("Data:  %d\n", *((int*) addr));

    addr = addr+1;

    printf("\nAddress: %p\n", addr);
    printf("Data:  %d\n", *((int*) addr));

    addr = addr+1;

    printf("\nAddress: %p\n", addr);
    printf("Data:  %d\n", *((int*) addr));

    addr = addr+1;

    printf("\nAddress: %p\n", addr);
    printf("Data:  %d\n", *((int*) addr));

    addr = addr+4;

    printf("\nAddress: %p\n", addr);
    printf("Data:  %d\n", *((int*) addr));
```

Output is:

```
 Address of Int Array 0 is: 0x7fff51b8ac30
 Address of Int Array 1 is: 0x7fff51b8ac34
 Address of Int Array 2 is: 0x7fff51b8ac38
 Address of Int Array 3 is: 0x7fff51b8ac3c

 Address: 0x7fff51b8ac30
 Data:  1

 Address: 0x7fff51b8ac31
 Data:  50331648

 Address: 0x7fff51b8ac32
 Data:  196608

 Address: 0x7fff51b8ac33
 Data:  768

 Address: 0x7fff51b8ac34
 Data:  3

 Address: 0x7fff51b8ac38
 Data:  4
```

But when I put a very large integer into the array, the following happens:

```
int ia[] = {2147483647, 3, 4, 7};

printf("Address of Int Array 0 is: %p\n", &ia[0]);
printf("Address of Int Array 1 is: %p\n", &ia[1]);

....
```

Output:

```
 Address of Int Array 0 is: 0x7fff51d1fc30
 Address of Int Array 1 is: 0x7fff51d1fc34
 Address of Int Array 2 is: 0x7fff51d1fc38
 Address of Int Array 3 is: 0x7fff51d1fc3c

 Address: 0x7fff51d1fc30
 Data:  2147483647

 Address: 0x7fff51d1fc31
 Data:  58720255

 Address: 0x7fff51d1fc32
 Data:  229375

 Address: 0x7fff51d1fc33
 Data:  895

 Address: 0x7fff51d1fc34
 Data:  3

 Address: 0x7fff51d1fc38
 Data:  4
```

I thought possibly (although unlikely) the large integer would be broken into bytes, one per memory address for a four byte integer, in keeping with byte-addressable memory, which seems to be the representation in C.  It appears from the code though that the first "memory address" is just a construct that actually holds a four byte integer.  If that’s the case, why must incremented memory addresses in C increment by the size of the data type, when it appears it’s just an abstraction?  Why can’t address 1 return 4 bytes, address 1 return 1 bytes, and so on — in particular if the data returned is smaller than the machine’s word size?

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. Arithmetic on `void *` is illegal in C.

Comment: Ok, good to know.  Didn't answer my question though.

Comment: It answers everything (whatever your problem is). Learn what _undefined behaviour_ means!

Comment: I'm not sure what more you want from an answer. Your test code is invalid so all the results are invalid. Thus there is nothing more to explain. The next step is really for you to fix the code and then reassess the results.

Comment: The last paragraph surmises that `int` element might be stored in bytes: it is, but the processor reads them all at once. Array elements are not of different size according to the data held, otherwise if you increase one value to a larger size - the whole array would have to be shuffled around. It's simpler than that. Every element is of type `int` which here is 4 bytes. When you work with the array *index* you don't consider the size of the elements, you just index as `array[0]` and `array[1]` etc. It's *the same* with pointer arithmetic: adding 1 takes you to the next element.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to understand why memory addresses for pointers increment a certain number of bytes based on datatype.

Because that's how pointer arithmetic works; if `p` is a pointer to an integer object (`int *p`), `p+1` will point to the *next integer object*.  If `p` is a pointer to a 10-element array of integers (`int (*p)[10]`), `p+1` will point to the *next 10-element array of integers*.

`p+1` always evaluates to the address of the next *object* following `p`; if the size of the object is 4 bytes, then `p+1` adds 4 to the value of `p`.  If the size of the object is 64 bytes, then `p+1` adds 64 to the value of `p`.

Answer (score 1):

> It appears the integers are stored in the 0 byte and random values in bytes 1-3

You didn't make your problem too clear, but this seems to be what you are confused about. First off, your code needs a bit of work: if you are doing byte-by-byte iteration, consider using a char pointer. void pointers in C aren't supposed to be used for arithmetic. And just to be nitpicky, use loops to avoid having to rewrite/copy-paste everything. [Here](http://ideone.com/BbS4Li) is some code that should clear things up, be sure to read the output.

Integers in C are often stored in 4 byte chunks (although depending on system architecture, it could be 2 or 8 bytes), each of these bytes are significant. That means that none of those values you were looking at were random: you just weren't looking at them correctly. You'll notice in the code above that I modified the output of the values:

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(ia); i++)
{
    printf("\nAddress: %p\n", addr);
    printf("Data:  0x%08x == %u\n", *((unsigned int*) addr), *((unsigned int*) addr));
    addr = addr + 1;
}
```

Note that sizeof(ia) returns the size of the array in bytes (4 items*4 bytes each = 16 bytes) and NOT the number of elements in the array. The %08x format specifier writes the integer data as a hex value, this way you can clearly see each byte of the output. I put the unsigned base10 value next to it, this is your so called 'random number'. The value 0x01 will translate into the integer 1, the value 0x0100 will be 256; by moving one byte you change the value drastically. It would be worth looking into endianness as well, it could help you understand the results.

Comment: In the event that Corry may not know, it is probably best to mention that `i < sizeof(ia)` is not `i < number of elements in array` but rather `i < size of pointer pointing to array`.

Comment: C does not enforce a specific size of integer types. and most architectures use 16 bit `int`. Also any part of an answer has to be **in** the answer, not an external site which can go offline anytime rendering your answer useless. And your answer also invokes UB.

Comment: @Olaf note that I said 'generally', I was only working with 32 bit integers because that is what OP's system appears to use. Additionally, I describe the changes I made to the code, and include the for loop (which is what produces the actual output) in my answer. Could you point out what invokes UB? I'd be happy to fix it.

Comment: @JacobH: "Generally" at least implies a majority. Don't just judge from what **you** know. C is a standardised language and the standard is well accepted. Relevant is what the standard says and that is very clear.

Comment: Okay, I'll fix the minor grammar mistake, I didn't mean for it to sound like I meant most systems. Now what about the undefined behaviour you mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for the help and the code for a new learner.  When I change ia[0] to a full four byte integer, it appears to still be stored in the 0 byte address space, likely the undefined behavior mentioned but not elaborated.  I’m trying to inspect each byte space in a four byte representation of an integer, to understand pointer address incrementation.  This may not be possible.  The wikipedia "Pointer" page has a table which shows how an array of ints would be stored in physical memory addresses on a 32-bit little-endian machine; this is what I’m trying and failing to investigate in the code.